# Web app traffic generation

Tags: seo, traffic, web-applications

I have created a small web app to easily transfer text across internet connected devices without relying on native clients. It basically works like pastebin with the addition of displaying a QR code of the link for easy scanning on a phone.

As I would like to monetize this to recoup my hosting costs (about 30 bucks a month since it's running it on Azure), the obvious solution would seem to put adsense banners and drive traffic to it.

How does one go about doing traffic generation for a web app where there's no content (text) to be written?

Comment: Sorry. I removed your link to prevent the question from being closed for being about one site in particular. I did quickly look at your site. You can put a bit of content about the web app in to help people understand what it is, what it can be used for, how it is unique, etc. You can tailor the content for search so that people who are looking for such an app can find it. As well, create back links where you can and do some PR work to announce the site. You want to be able to explain your app to people like me who look at it and wonder what what *this thing* is for and how it can benefit me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice and for removing the link. Should I put the content you are talking about in a single page (basically expand on what I have in the About page) or try to split it up in blog posts? If the former, better to have it on the front page itself or somewhere else to make the front less cluttered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your website. I am tech savvy, but was not sure what to do with the app.

I recommend creating a few pages of content to attract users. Do not bury them or add them to any existing page. You can have pages that explain:

- What the app does.
- What users the app is good for.
- Why the app is useful.
- How to use the app.

You can combine some of these into a single page- such as the first 3. But I would keep the *how to use* page separate. The more you can say, the better. The more pages you can create with content the better. You are not only creating pages to help users, but also should perform well in search. That is the point. You want to create enough content to attract search users and please search engines. You cannot escape that fact that search engines want content. The more you can create, the better. However, I do also understand this could be a bit difficult- How much can you say?, for example. But do the best you can. Link all of these pages from the home page and link each page to the app and to the other pages where it makes sense.